# Normalize columns names in ORACLE 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need remove the quotes from the names of the columns in many tables in my schema. there is any way to automate this process?, any function in oracle or some tool that allows me to change the names of the columns removing the quotes. I am using oracle 11g.

**UPDATE**

I'm sorry, I had to rephrase my question.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of all the case sensitive column names

```
SQL> create table foo ( "x" number );

Table created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  begin
  2    for x in (select *
  3                from user_tab_cols
  4               where column_name != UPPER(column_name))
  5    loop
  6      execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE ' || x.table_name ||
  7        ' RENAME column "' || x.column_name || '"' ||
  8        ' TO ' || upper(x.column_name);
  9    end loop;
 10* end;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> desc foo
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 X                                                  NUMBER
```

Comment: This rocks! However, since we did not know in our environment who else might have written queries against tables in our schema using quoted column names, we limited our inner user_tab_cols query to only affect the tables we knew were safe for us to modify.  Otherwise we might have broken someone else's code, since their potential use of a quoted column name in embedded SQL would then have not found a camel-case column name we had subsequently upper-cased.  Thanks a ton for this.

Answer (score 6):

I assume here by "fields" you mean "column names".

Keep in mind that column names in Oracle are not case sensitive unless you put them in quotes when creating the table. It's generally not a good idea to use quotes around the column names when creating the table. In other words, if you create the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
  colUMN1 varchar2(10),
  CoLumn2 number(38)
)
```

Then you can still run select statements like this:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM FOO
```

You can also do this:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM FOO
```

Also note that if you run this query, you'll see that Oracle stored the column names as uppercase in the data dictionary:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FOO'
```

So there's no need to rename these columns to all uppercase. The queries you write can use all uppercase column names (assuming the tables weren't created using quotes around the column names) and they'll work fine. It's generally a bad idea to try to force them to be case sensitive.

Comment: just check the tables in the database and the problem is that were created using quotes.

Comment: This is obscure, but... anyone transferring Corel Paradox 9 tables over to Oracle using the Paradox TCursor "copy()" function should know that Paradox 9 does indeed copy the table to Oracle using quoted column names by default.  Our bulk transfer of old tables to a new Oracle schema would have been otherwise painful without the sweeping cleanup given by Mr. Justin Cave above.